# React useReducer empties initialState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

i'm trying to use some data fetched by axios inside initialState so I can use it with useReducer later on. but as soon as I pass it as the initialState of my second argument it returns an empty array with no objects. please help... :(

```
 const [prods, setProds] = useState([]);
  const getProds = () => {
    axios.get(`API`).then((res) => {
      const data = res.data;
      setProds(data.products);
    });
  };


  const result = prods.map(function (el) {
    const quantity = Object.assign({}, el);
    quantity.count = 0;
    return quantity;
  });
  
  const initialState = {
    products: [result],
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getProds();
  }, []);

console.log(initialState);

  const [countState, dispatch] = useReducer(counterReducer, initialState);

  console.log(countState);
```

and the result from the first and second log looks like :

[useReducer empties initialState](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El2Pj.png)

the result from API call after adding the count to each looks something like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxzKQ.png)

and here's the code for my reducer, I checked it many times but seems fine :

```
export const counterReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      return {
        ...state,
        products: state.products.map((product) =>
          product.id === action.id
            ? { ...product, count: product.count + 1 }
            : product
        ),
      };

    case "decrement":
      return {
        ...state,
        products: state.products.map((product) =>
          product.id === action.id
            ? {
                ...product,
                count: product.count !== 1 ? product.count - 1 : 1,
              }
            : product
        ),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: In the API response it looks like `products` is an array with one entry, and the entry is another array with 12 entries. So to iterate the products you’d have to do `products[0].map(...)` instead of `products.map(...)`. (This seems like an odd structure for the API to return if you ask me.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`useReducer` consumes `initialState` only on first render(before axios finished), on all the subsequent rerenders it will just return the state from the memory cell.
What you want to do is to call `useReducer` at the top

```js
const [countState, dispatch] = useReducer(counterReducer, {products: []});
```

and then call `dispatch` in your `getProds`

```js
const getProds = () => {
    axios.get(`API`).then((res) => {
      const data = res.data;
      setProds(data.products);
      dispatch({ type: "PRODUCTS_FETCHED", payload: data.products});
    });
  };
```

And also add according case in your reducer to set the state.

```js
export const counterReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      return {
        ...state,
        products: state.products.map((product) =>
          product.id === action.id
            ? { ...product, count: product.count + 1 }
            : product
        ),
      };

    case "decrement":
      return {
        ...state,
        products: state.products.map((product) =>
          product.id === action.id
            ? {
                ...product,
                count: product.count !== 1 ? product.count - 1 : 1,
              }
            : product
        ),
      };
    case "PRODUCTS_FETCHED":
      return {
        ...state,
        products: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: thank you sooooooooooooo much! you just made my day! guess I still have a lot to learn on the whole react and reducer life cycle :D <3